# How do I read this?

Tags: analysis, notation

I received the following equation.  It is supposed to contain clues to something I have to solve.  I am not familiar with the math symbols used here.

How do I read the following:

```
f: R → D, ∀d ∈ D, ∃!r ∈ R: f(r) = Lm = d
```

Comment: If you provide more context maybe we can decipher that `Lm`.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : Sir, I am extremely sorry to fork an off-topic discussion here. But I am really in need of some help sir. I wanted to prove that if $p^{2m-2n}-p^m+3p^{m-2n}+1$ is a perfect square then $m=2n$. Here the $p$ is a odd-prime and all the exponents are positive. I tried to post this but I am not clear myself. So I have deleted twice. If you can give some hints, it would be extremely useful. I tried using the Reductio ad absurdum . We then get 2 cases $m \lt 2n$ and $m \gt 2n$. Then I am stuck here.. I would be very happy to hear any suggestion from you sir..

Comment: @Iyengar: I cannot help you with number theory questions.

Answer (score 5):

It says that $f$ is a function from $R$ to $D$, and for each $d\in D$ there is exactly one $r\in R$ with the property that $f(r)=d$. I can’t help with the $Lm$: it isn’t a standard notation and appears to be something derived from the context.

The symbols $\forall$ and $\exists!$ are quantifiers meaning respectively ‘for each’ and ‘there exists exactly one’.

Comment: Also, something like $d \in D$ means "$d$, which is an element of the set $D$".

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that by $R$ you mean $\mathbb R$, the set of real numbers:

- $f\colon\mathbb R\to D$ means that $f$ is a *function* from the real numbers to a set $D$.
- $\forall d\in D$ is read "For every $d$ which is an element of $D$",
- $\exists!r\in\mathbb R$ is to say "Exists a unique real number $r$"
- $: f(r) = Lm = d$ such that $f(r)=Lm$, which as Brian said is not a standard notation, and also $f(r)=d$.

This means that $f$ is such function that for every $d\in D$ there is exactly one $r$ such that $f(r)=d$. This means that every two numbers are mapped to two distinct elements of $D$; such $f$ is called **injective**. We also deduce that *every* $d\in D$ is $f(r)$ for some $r$, and such $f$ is called **surjective**. If a function is both injective and surjective we say that it is **bijective**, or that it is a **bijection**.